# Trouble with mysql SELECT inside SELECT statement with MATCH AGAINST

Tags: mysql, select, match

I have a MySQL statement where I am trying to replace a character in a field and then matching it against a keyword, but I keep getting an error. Any suggestions

```
SELECT 
    x.new_content 
FROM 
    ( SELECT REPLACE(content,'x', 'y') as new_content FROM articles )x 
WHERE 
MATCH
    ( x.new_content ) 
AGAINST
    ( 'keyword' ) 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

and got an error:

```
error: #1210 - Incorrect arguments to AGAINST
```

Comment: What does "keyword" look like?

Comment: 'keyword' is just a string, no spaces or anything special. The actual  query I am running it may be multiple words with and look like '+*keyword1* +*keyword2*'. but I cant even get the query to work in its simplest form.